# How to find the mean and variance of minimum of two dependent random variables?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Assume that $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are identical independent Gaussian random variables. I'd like to compute the **mean** and **variance** of $S=\min\{P, Q\}$, where :
$$Q=(X-Y)^2$$ and
$$P=(X-Z)^2$$
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

$$
\begin{split}
1 - F_S(s)
 &= 1 - \mathbb{P}[\min\{P,Q\} \le s] \\
 &= \mathbb{P}[\min\{P,Q\} > s] \\
 &= \mathbb{P}[P > s, Q > s] \\
 &= \mathbb{P}[(X-Y)^2 > s, (X-Z)^2 > s]
\end{split}
$$
which is a triple integral over the correct domain of $(X,Y,Z)$... can you finish it?

Comment: Let assume that $X, Y, Z\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then $P, Q\sim \text{Gamma}(\frac{1}{2},4\sigma^2)$. $\mathbb{E}[S]$ can be expressed as:
$$\mathbb{E}[S]=\int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}[\min(P,Q)\geq t]dt$$
I couldn't solve the integral.

Comment: Also, I believe there is a mistake in your hint. The correct expression should be:
$$F_S(s) = \mathbb{P}[\min\{P,Q\} \le s] = \mathbb{P}[P \le s~ \text{or}~ Q \le s]
       = \mathbb{P}[(X-Y)^2 \le s ~\text{or}~ (X-Z)^2 \le s]$$

Comment: @Saed you are right, updating

Comment: @Saed, updated. Write the final probability as a triple integral in $(X,Y,Z)$, to capture the correct dependence between $P$ and $Q$.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done so far:
$$F_S(s) = \mathbb{P}[\min\{P,Q\} \le s]$$ $$ = \mathbb{P}[P \le s~ \text{or}~ Q \le s] $$      $$ = \mathbb{P}[(X-Y)^2 \le s ~\text{or}~ (X-Z)^2 \le s]$$    $$ = \mathbb{P}[(X-Y)^2 \le s ]+\mathbb{P}[(X-Z)^2 \le s]$$  $$ = \mathbb{P}[-\sqrt{s} \le X-Y \le \sqrt{s}]+ \mathbb{P}[-\sqrt{s} \le X-Z \le \sqrt{s}]$$    $$ = \mathbb{P}[Y-\sqrt{s} \le X \le Y+\sqrt{s}]+ \mathbb{P}[Z-\sqrt{s} \le X \le Z+\sqrt{s}]$$   $$ =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \int_{y-\sqrt{s}}^{y+\sqrt{s}}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \int_{z-\sqrt{s}}^{z+\sqrt{s}}f_{X,Z}(x,z)dxdz $$

Is that correct?